# Finding rows in SQL where changes but only certain changes while keeping others

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scenario where I want each occurrence of an active row to bring back that row in my result set and also inactive if there is only 1 inactive record for that IDENTIFIER and also if there are more than 1 active also show those.  I've used Row_Number function and then in another query show where the row = '1' but if I do that row 1s only come back and then I lose some of my desired results.  To restate my issue is I want all active records to come back and only inactive where IDENTIFIER is unique.  The row that is bold should not be shown in the results.
**1 has 1 active record in the DB.

2 has 2 active and 1 inactive records.

3 has no active records.

4 has only 2 active records, no inactive.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a windowed conditional count,** this has the benfit of only scanning the table once

```
SELECT
    t.IDENTIFIER,
    t.DB_ID,
    t.Status
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        HasActive = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Active' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.IDENTIFIER)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.Status = 'Active' OR t.HasActive = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Status = 'Active'
   OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM tablename t2 
            WHERE t2.identifier = t1.identifier AND t2.db_id <> t1.db_id
          );
```

I assume that the column `db_id` is unique, at least for the same `identifier`.

Comment: It's a unique relationship, there can be a 1 to many relationship between where IDENTIFIER can have more than DB_ID attached to it.

Comment: @JBPhotogKY but db_id is unique in each identifier, right?

Comment: Yes it is, I misinterpreted what you said.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is my variant.

```
select IDENTIFIER, [DB_ID], [Status]
from Tab
where [Status]='Active'
union
select IDENTIFIER, [DB_ID], [Status]
from Tab as t
where [Status]='Inactive' And 1=(select Count(*) from Tab where 
IDENTIFIER=t.IDENTIFIER)
Order by IDENTIFIER, [DB_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this, because (rank=1 and Status=Inactive) only if there are no active rows for a particular Identifier

```
select * from (
select *,     
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier order by status) AS rank
from some_table
)
where rank=1 or status = 'Active'
```